# R - Need help simulating estimators

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution

I am given two estimators, `T1 = ((X1+X2)/2)*(Y1+Y2)/2)` and 
`T2 = (X1*Y1+X2*Y2)/2`.

This is used for finding an estimate area, for example, `T1 = ((503+505)/2)*((334+330)/2)` and `T2 = ((503*334 + 505*330)/2)`.

`X1, X2` are normally distributed with average `µ1` and variance `σ^2`
and `Y1,Y2` are normally distributed with average `µ2` and variance `σ^2`. Now I wish to simulate this data with 10^4 samples. I was wondering what are the relevant commands I need to use. I am thinking rnorm, but I'm not quite sure how I would go about using this.

Comment: Yes, you should use `rnorm`.

Comment: @Roland How am I supposed to use these estimators in rnorm though? Would something like this be correct for `T1`,
`(((rnorm(10^4,0,1)+rnorm(10^4,0,1))/2)*((rnorm(10^4,0,1)+rnorm(10^4,0,1))/2)` I want to compare the standard deviations of these estimators

Comment: Why do you doubt that your code is correct?

Comment: @Roland I am new to R and not sure if I'm doing this correct - for example I'm just taking the mean to be 0 and standard deviation to be 1. I'm not entirely sure if I'm doing the right thing.

Comment: Read the examples for `?rnorm`. Create x1, x2, y1, and y2, assuming some values for µ and σ^2. Them compute T1 and T2 and analyze with `summary()`, `sd()`, or other functions from packages, like `?psych::describe()`

Comment: Since I'm going to find the sd of these estimators would it be fine to assume µ = 0 and σ^2 = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both `T1` and `T2` rely on `X1`, `X2`, `Y1`, and `Y2`, you should first simulate those four random variables:

```
X1 <- rnorm(1e4, mu1, sigma)
X2 <- rnorm(1e4, mu1, sigma)
Y1 <- rnorm(1e4, mu2, sigma)
Y2 <- rnorm(1e4, mu2, sigma)
```

Then you can run your code to get all simulated values of `T1` and `T2`:

```
T1 <- ((X1+X2)/2)*(Y1+Y2)/2)
T2 <- (X1*Y1+X2*Y2)/2
```